# Android/IOS Turnbased multiplayer game (like WordFeud/Scrabble)

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, multiplayer

I've been looking around for some time, but can't seem te find the right answer.

I'm trying te develop a android multiplayergame, later it must also be able to connect to IOS and Windows Mobile 8.

It's a game like WordFeud/Scrabble for up to 4 players per game.

What I want to do is do most of the complex coding like validations, synchronisations of the playboard, stats, etc on my asp.NET server. (since I'm a C# programmer).

So the app on the device will be the GUI and some logic to sync.

Now things like auto-sync(or push), turnbased, find player etc.

How can I do this?

And is this the way to go when I want worldwide thousands of players to be able to play against eachother?

From my reseach using a webservice for the sync/game logic seems a logic option.

I don't feel much for tools like Parse, Skiller, Openfeint, etc.
Since they all cost a lot of money and you are depending on them.

Kinds Regars!

Comment: you have to narrow down you requirements you wanted to support three OS and thousands of players and don't wanna pay money^^ :-) this is not difficult goal can be achieved with Photon multiplayer library, perhaps XMPP could also help...

Comment: @staticvoidmain Well I would pay money if needed. But since I know c#.net webservices I would like to use that as a base for the game.
But it would need to support some kind of push to notify the other devices that player x has made a move. And also I would have to work good global (my server is in The Netherlands).